# How to get current Session value of Captcha?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

Please help me anyone! I'm stuck!

I'm trying to compare value inserted in textfield and value shown in Captcha (image), if they match it will show **alert('Yes!')** otherwise **alert('No!')**. But when I trying to get session value of Captcha (`request.getSession().getAttribute("captcha")`) it gets previous value of it!

How to make sure that value of Catcha if the same as user sees on image?

**Captcha.jsp:**

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.awt.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.awt.image.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.imageio.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.awt.geom.*"%>
<%
    String imageFormat = "jpg";
    response.setContentType("image/" + imageFormat);

    try {
        // you can pass in fontSize, width, height via the request

        Color backgroundColor = Color.red;
        Color borderColor = Color.black;
        Color textColor = Color.white;
        Color circleColor = new Color(160, 160, 160);
        Font textFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, paramInt(request,
                "fontSize", 24));
        int charsToPrint = 6;
        int width = paramInt(request, "width", 150);
        int height = paramInt(request, "height", 80);
        int circlesToDraw = 6;
        float horizMargin = 20.0f;
        float imageQuality = 0.95f; // max is 1.0 (this is for jpeg)
        double rotationRange = 0.7; // this is radians
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bufferedImage.getGraphics();

        g.setColor(backgroundColor);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        // lets make some noisey circles
        g.setColor(circleColor);
        for (int i = 0; i < circlesToDraw; i++) {
            int circleRadius = (int) (Math.random() * height / 2.0);
            int circleX = (int) (Math.random() * width - circleRadius);
            int circleY = (int) (Math.random() * height - circleRadius);
            g.drawOval(circleX, circleY, circleRadius * 2,
                    circleRadius * 2);
        }

        g.setColor(textColor);
        g.setFont(textFont);

        FontMetrics fontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();
        int maxAdvance = fontMetrics.getMaxAdvance();
        int fontHeight = fontMetrics.getHeight();

        // i removed 1 and l and i because there are confusing to users...
        // Z, z, and N also get confusing when rotated
        // 0, O, and o are also confusing...
        // lowercase G looks a lot like a 9 so i killed it
        // this should ideally be done for every language...
        // i like controlling the characters though because it helps prevent confusion
        String elegibleChars = "ABCDEFGHJKLMPQRSTUVWXYabcdefhjkmnpqrstuvwxy23456789";
        char[] chars = elegibleChars.toCharArray();

        float spaceForLetters = -horizMargin * 2 + width;
        float spacePerChar = spaceForLetters / (charsToPrint - 1.0f);

        AffineTransform transform = g.getTransform();

        StringBuffer finalString = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < charsToPrint; i++) {
            double randomValue = Math.random();
            int randomIndex = (int) Math.round(randomValue * (chars.length - 1));
            char characterToShow = chars[randomIndex];
            finalString.append(characterToShow);

            // this is a separate canvas used for the character so that
            // we can rotate it independently
            int charImageWidth = maxAdvance * 2;
            int charImageHeight = fontHeight * 2;
            int charWidth = fontMetrics.charWidth(characterToShow);
            int charDim = Math.max(maxAdvance, fontHeight);
            int halfCharDim = (int) (charDim / 2);

            BufferedImage charImage = new BufferedImage(charDim,
                    charDim, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D charGraphics = charImage.createGraphics();
            charGraphics.translate(halfCharDim, halfCharDim);
            double angle = (Math.random() - 0.5) * rotationRange;
            charGraphics.transform(AffineTransform
                    .getRotateInstance(angle));
            charGraphics.translate(-halfCharDim, -halfCharDim);
            charGraphics.setColor(textColor);
            charGraphics.setFont(textFont);

            int charX = (int) (0.5 * charDim - 0.5 * charWidth);
            charGraphics
                    .drawString(
                            "" + characterToShow,
                            charX,
                            (int) ((charDim - fontMetrics.getAscent()) / 2 + fontMetrics
                                    .getAscent()));

            float x = horizMargin + spacePerChar * (i) - charDim / 2.0f;
            int y = (int) ((height - charDim) / 2);
            //System.out.println("x=" + x + " height=" + height + " charDim=" + charDim + " y=" + y + " advance=" + maxAdvance + " fontHeight=" + fontHeight + " ascent=" + fontMetrics.getAscent());
            g.drawImage(charImage, (int) x, y, charDim, charDim, null, null);

            charGraphics.dispose();
        }

        // let's do the border
        g.setColor(borderColor);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);

        //Write the image as a jpg
        Iterator iter = ImageIO
                .getImageWritersByFormatName(imageFormat);
        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) iter.next();
            ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
            if (imageFormat.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg")
                    || imageFormat.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")) {
                iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
                iwp.setCompressionQuality(imageQuality);
            }
            writer.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(response.getOutputStream()));
            IIOImage imageIO = new IIOImage(bufferedImage, null, null);
            writer.write(null, imageIO, iwp);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("no encoder found for jsp");
        }

        // set session
        request.getSession().setAttribute("captcha", finalString.toString()); 

System.out.println("Captcha.jsp: "+request.getSession().getAttribute("captcha"));//for console output

        out.clear();
        out = pageContext.pushBody();


        g.dispose();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to build image", ioe);
    }
%>

<%!public static String paramString(HttpServletRequest request,
        String paramName, String defaultString) {
    return request.getParameter(paramName) != null ? request
            .getParameter(paramName) : defaultString;
}

public static int paramInt(HttpServletRequest request, String paramName,
        int defaultInt) {
    return request.getParameter(paramName) != null ? Integer
            .parseInt(request.getParameter(paramName)) : defaultInt;
}%>
```

To set sesion I'm using - `request.getSession().setAttribute("captcha", finalString.toString());`

**ValidateCapture.jsp:**

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function ValidateCaptcha(){
    <%String captcha=(String)request.getSession().getAttribute("captcha");%>
    var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
    var captcha = '<%=captcha%>';

    if(answer==captcha){
        alert('Yes');
    }
    else{
        alert('No');
    }
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
    <img src="Captcha.jsp"/>
    <input id="answer" type="text">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="ValidateCaptcha();">
    <%System.out.println("ValidateCapture.jsp: "+request.getSession().getAttribute("captcha"));%> <!--for console output-->
</body>
```

To get session I'm using - `request.getSession().getAttribute("captcha");`

**Console Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i saw the code. expecially about set session. i thought you shouldn't set attribute value. First, session invalid just when The browser closed or no-operation time up 30 mins in tomcat configuration file. however,you didn't close your browser,you will get the same captcha with previous value of it. so, we can do this,follow the code: `request.setAttribute("captcha", finalString.toString());`//set value and `request.getAttribute("captcha");//get value`

---

like this.we will get different captcha values when we click the pictures.Request Object also changed. why do this? because  when "Request" to  server and server responsed later,request Object invalid. next request will produce new request object.just this,good luck.

Comment: So actually you asking me to add this line - **request.getAttribute("captcha");** after this line - **request.setAttribute("captcha", finalString.toString());** inside **Captcha.jsp**? I just did it but still have got the same output :(